# Why doesn't my LTSpice simulation get the same results as this one?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

Here's what i want to have as a result:

[image]

Here is what i have:

[image]

I have an ideal op amp and the green curve only hits 5 Volts when input is 2.7V, in the video it's 2.55. The green curve only hits 0 volts when input is 2.3V, in the video it's 2.45 V.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running in to speed issues with the opamp where the output is delayed from the input which gives the impression that your hysteresis band is wider. Slow down your ramp so your rise and fall times are 500ms like the TI demonstration and you'll get results closer to the TI demo..

Also, opamps have issues being used as a comparator since coming out of saturation will cause excess delays. Better to use a comparator which is made to quickly come out of saturation. You can use the LT1017 which is slow enough to see issues if your ramp time is too fast.

Answer (score 4):

You can import  [3rd party models into LT spice](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579239882001.html) such as the [spice model](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sbom859) for the [TLV1701](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV1701). Common mode voltages are probably different from the part that you currently have in LT spice.

Using the same part in LT spice should correct the issue (assuming TI actually modeled the part in spice correctly, which you cannot guarantee)

Answer (score 2):

Use a comparator instead of the ideal opamp. Try the built in LT1721 or similar. TI doesn't offer models easily compatible with LTSPice, to my knowledge.

Comment: While generally true, it looks like OP uses `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp`, which can be configured to be a comparator, too.

Comment: TI offers spice models on most of it's parts, and they are compatible with most spice programs

Comment: @VoltageSpike, you were totally correct. At least for two of the five TI parts in my recent design I was able to find models and convert them using these steps here pretty trivially. 
https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/ltspice_creating_a_schematic_symbol.pdf